# WP_Query's "request" SQL Query

Tags: wp-query, search

Lets say that I want to use a MongoDB for searching. I saw that `WP_Query` has a property named `request` which it seems that holds the SQL Query which is executed on the SQL database.

Now if I write a translator from SQL to MongoDB would that be enough to create a valid WP Search? Or for complex search WP Might use some extra (pre/after) processing in which case it will run some other SQL Queries?